# NodeJS Express: CORS enabled and still not working

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I'm having a huge problem with CORS.
I'm developing in AngularJS using NodeJS Express and I have another API running in another IP/PORT (both are in the same machine).  I'm coding functions in Angular to consume the API.

When I try to get/post/delete/put I receive this message:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:3000' is therefore not allowed access.

There's a lot of solutions here in Stackoverflow to configure the app.js. One configuration that I've tried and still not working:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
next();
});
```

I have installed the npm cors module. I've edited my app.js to enable the cors module and still not working:

```
var express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors');  
app.use(cors());
```

Any solutions? I have no idea how to fix it! Btw I'm using Chrome.

Comment: You're adding those to the API server, right?

Comment: What do your ajax calls look like?  Are they all GET requests?  Do they have any custom headers?  DELETE and PUT will require support for the `OPTIONS` command because the browser will preflight those wiht OPTIONS first to see if cross-origin is allowed.  Custom headers can also force a pre-flight OPTIONS request.

Comment: @robertklep Wow! I thought that I needed to config the NodeJS server and not the API! Now it's working fine :D

Comment: Victor, what do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

Put this in your http request on angular

```
$http.post(url, {withCredentials: true, ...})
```

Also you can put this config in app.js for all requests:

```
$httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

put the following in your app.js file:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
})
```

and then use the 'CORS' module in each of the routes:

```
router.post('/create',cors(), function (req,res) {
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what works for me on Node.js v6.4.0 and Express 4.13.4

There was no need for me to use the cors module. Simply:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept")
    next()
})
```